# n features for data and the input test set are different after applying one hot encoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I've been trying to train a RandomForestRegressor to predict house data prices for a given test set from the given training set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler

file='file:///F:/Download sort required/train.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(file)
data.dropna(axis=0,subset=['SalePrice'],inplace=True)
y=data.SalePrice

predictors=['LotArea','OverallQual','GrLivArea','GarageCars','TotRmsAbvGrd','Neighborhood','HouseStyle','YearBuilt','ExterQual','KitchenQual']

One_hot_encoded_predictors=['Neighborhood','HouseStyle','YearBuilt','ExterQual','KitchenQual']

X_uncoded=data[predictors]
#Encoding the training data
X_uncoded=pd.get_dummies(X_uncoded,columns=One_hot_encoded_predictors)
X=X_uncoded


maxabsscaler=MaxAbsScaler()
X_max_abs=maxabsscaler.fit_transform(X)
model=RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_max_abs,y)

test_file='file:///C:/Users/shand/Downloads/test.csv'
test_data=pd.read_csv(test_file)
X_uncoded_test=test_data[predictors]
X_uncoded_test=pd.get_dummies(X_uncoded_test,columns=One_hot_encoded_predictors)
X_test=X_uncoded_test
X_test.fillna(X_test.mean(),inplace=True)
X_max_abs_test=maxabsscaler.fit_transform(X_test)

predicted_prices=model.predict(X_max_abs_test)

my_submission = pd.DataFrame({'Id': test_data.Id, 'SalePrice': predicted_prices})
my_submission.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
```

I applied one hot encoding on the categorical features followed by a maxabsscaler transformation as most of the data varied either from -1 to 1 or 0 to 1. But the code upon compilation throws the following error-

```
> >  28 X_test.fillna(X_test.mean(),inplace=True)
>      29 X_max_abs_test=maxabsscaler.fit_transform(X_test)
> ---> 30 predicted_prices=model.predict(X_max_abs_test)
>      31 my_submission = pd.DataFrame({'Id': test_data.Id, 'SalePrice': predicted_prices})
>      32 my_submission.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
> 
> C:\Users\shand\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py
> in predict(self, X)
>     683         """
>     684         # Check data
> --> 685         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
>     686 
>     687         # Assign chunk of trees to jobs
> 
> C:\Users\shand\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py
> in _validate_X_predict(self, X)
>     353                                  "call `fit` before exploiting the model.")
>     354 
> --> 355         return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
>     356 
>     357     @property
> 
> C:\Users\shand\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in
> _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
>     374                              "match the input. Model n_features is %s and "
>     375                              "input n_features is %s "
> --> 376                              % (self.n_features_, n_features))
>     377 
>     378         return X
> 
> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input.
> Model n_features is 158 and input n_features is 151
```

There are 158 features that are used to train the model after applying the one hot encoding and maxabsscaler.
Can anyone explain why i am getting this error although i applied the same transformation to both the training set and the test set data?
What should i do to correct this error?

PS-Data was obtained from -
https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

Comment: You are aware you can use newlines to make your code more readable?

Comment: Sorry @COLDSPEED! added newlines. Could you please explain why this error is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned number of columns in train and test data after encoding is different.
train data has 158 column where as test data has only 151 columns.

```
#Encoding the train data
X_uncoded=pd.get_dummies(X_uncoded,columns=One_hot_encoded_predictors)
X=X_uncoded
print(X.shape)
(1460, 158)
#Encoding the test data
X_uncoded_test=pd.get_dummies(X_uncoded_test,columns=One_hot_encoded_predictors)
print(X_uncoded_test.shape)
(1459, 151)
```

This could be because test data has lesser number of levels than train data. See the example below from [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))
pd.get_dummies(s)
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```

You can consider combining train and test before encoding and then separate them back to train and test after encoding as described [here](http://fastml.com/how-to-use-pd-dot-get-dummies-with-the-test-set/)

Comment: The same is explained here too https://www.kaggle.com/learn-forum/50008#post299111